# How to add navigation controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I use code below, but it is not loaded:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.mapViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];

self.navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:self.navigationBar];

[self.navigationController.navigationController pushViewController:self.mapViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: `self.navigationController.navigationController` will always be `nil`. A navigation controller can never be in another navigation controller.

Comment: It also makes no sense to create and an assign a navigation controller like this in a view controller. Normally you would create the navigation controller at a higher level and set it up with a root view controller. Then when the view controller want to push another view controller (like here), you simply push the new view controller onto `self.navigationController`.

Comment: without it, it not shows too..

Comment: You should read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try as below

```
UIViewController *bbp=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bbp];
// [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
  [passcodeNavigationController release];
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked at a lot of issues, but only this answer helped me :) Works at iOS 9.

Comment: I'm getting the next error:'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your `AppDelegate.m` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME" bundle:nil];
yourViewControllerClassName *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_ID"];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

`yourViewControllerClassName` is the .h and .m file name that is linked to your viewController.

`YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME` is the name of your .storyboard file. For example, fill in `Main` if your .storyboard file is called `Main.storyboard`.

`YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_ID` is the ID for your veiwController. You can edit it in the `Identity inspector`.(See photo)

[image]

Hope this helps:)